What is the physical significance of the electromagnetic tensor $F^{\mu\nu}$ having its indices on top or bottom?
I understand we need to put indices on a four vector on the top or bottom like $A^{\mu}$ or $A_{\mu}$ because of the invariant Lorentz product having its later three terms negative (for $+ - - -$ signature); so $A^{\mu}A_{\mu}$ is defined to have negative sign before it for $\mu=1,2,3$ and positive sign for $\mu=0$. So the upper or lower indices in this case are for mathematical convenience; so we can express the Lorentz product with ease. But in EM tensor, what does the change in indices position signify?
Also can someone please explain this?
$$F_{\alpha\beta}=\eta_{\alpha\gamma}\eta_{\beta\delta}F^{\gamma\delta}$$

See the sign differences here. It's a special case of what happens with rank-$2$ tensors, because the electromagnetic tensor is antisymmetric.

Related question: Difference between the contravariant, covariant and mixed form of the electromagnetic tensor and Minkowski metric tensor?

Do you understand that $A_\mu=\eta_{\mu\nu}A^\nu$? Contraction with the metric raises or lowers individual indices.

@Ghoster Yes I do know it.

@ThomasFritsch But why do we need covariant and contravariant form (lower and upper indices) of the electromagnetic tensor?

@J.G. It says in the link that indices will change in electromagnetic tensor for change in reference frame. Can someone please explain?

Why do we need covariant and contravariant form? You don’t “need” them; you could always write any expression in terms of only $F^{\mu\nu}$ or $F_{\mu\nu}$ and the metric tensor. But, just like $A^\mu A_\mu$ is a nice compact notation to write that Lorentz invariant, so is $F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}$ (the invariant that appears in the EM action).

Yes I do know it. Well, the equation you asked about is just doing that on each of the two tensor indices.

@Ghoster About your last comment, the brought change in position of the indices is it abstract mathematics?

I’d call it “formalism”. Contravariant and covariant components have the same physical content. You don’t get something physically different (at least not in any important way) by raising or lowering an index. The formalism lets you write Lorentz invariants (and also form-invariant equations) without having to write lots of metric factors everywhere.

If you haven’t seen $F^{\mu\nu}$ and $F_{\mu\nu}$ written out explicitly as matrices whose entries are components of $\vec E$ and $\vec B$, you should look those up or compute them. They differ by just a few signs in some components.

If you understood that there is no physical significance to writing the potential with its index up or down, why would it be any different for the field?

@Ghoster Thank you for clarifying we are dealing with some type of 'formalism' here, this helped. But what is going one here? $$F^{'}{\mu\nu} = \Lambda{\mu}^{\alpha} \Lambda_{\nu}^{\beta} F_{\alpha\beta} $$

Is it only strictly following the defined way? But then how can we decide things like "what appears to be magnetic field to one observer looks like an electric field to another" from this? How are we exactly extracting the physical information here?

What is going on here? That’s the Lorentz transformation for the covariant field components. This question is about upper vs. lower indices in one frame, so introducing a transformation between frames creates a different question that shouldn’t be asked as a comment on this question. To understand this transformation in more detail, pick a $\Lambda$ corresponding to a boost along some axis and write out the components of $F$ to find how $\vec E$ and $\vec B$ mix under that change of frame.

Regarding to your final question, the formula is telling you the way the tensor transforms under a defined metric. It changes from contravariant tensor to covariant tensor in such way.

I actually wanted to know how we get that expression.

It's all about the mathematics underneath 2nd rank tensors. If you want, this is the tool needed to change from lower to upper indices. The exact procedure to get this, i cant remember but Differential geometry and tensor calculus courses might be useful to understand special/general relativiy

Answering the question in your comment

But why do we need covariant and contravariant form (lower and
upper indices) of the electromagnetic tensor?

In specical relativity you need both of them.
The natural way to write the Lorentz 4-force is with
the lower indices electromagnetic tensor:
$$f_\mu=qF_{\mu\nu}U^\nu$$
The inhomogenous Maxwell's equations are most easily
written with the lower indices electromagnetic tensor:
$$\partial_{[\alpha}F_{\beta\gamma]}=0$$
And the homogenous Maxwell's equations are most easily
written with the upper indices electromagnetic tensor:
$$\partial_\alpha F^{\alpha\beta}=\mu_0 J^\beta$$

Adding to the current answer, you may think of the equation in your post in a component-to-component basis. For example, for the element $F_{00}$ you have (taking the Minkowski metric)
$$F_{00}=\eta_{00}\eta_{00}F^{00} +\eta_{01}\eta_{00}F^{10} +\eta_{00}\eta_{01}F^{01} + \eta_{01}\eta_{01}F^{11} + \cdots = F^{00}+0+0+0+\cdots+0 = F^{00}. $$
The same for all other components. The Minkowski metric is diagonal so most components are zero, simplifying the summation.
